# Dynamically add textbox if the database value is Text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a database field call "type" (TextBox, DropDown, CheckBox) and "value" column. I need to read the type and display in the webpage dynamically using VB.net.

Example: If the database type is TextBox I need to display a TextBox in the webpage and when user enters a value in the TextBox, this needs to update to the database field "value".

How do I dynamically add textbox if the database value is Text in vb.net?

Comment: Don't u know `how to dynamically add Text box in your application` You  can search it on the internet as well.. You will get many solutions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It will check the value of **MyDatabaseType** which you should get from your database. If the value is  **"TextBox"**, it will create a `TextBox` and add it to the form **MyForm**:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
  If MyDatabaseType = "TextBox" Then
    Dim TextBox1 As New TextBox
    TextBox1.ID = "TextBox1"
    MyForm.Controls.Add(TextBox1)
  End If

  InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

For more details, you can check [this article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515).